# AMPL Matrix of Varying Sized Sets Generation

Tags: set, ampl

I have a question related to AMPL. I'm trying to construct a matrix of sets, named A in the following code (part of the .mod file). This gives an error message of "A is already defined."

Please note that S, T are parameters and B is a set in .dat file. (They have already been read by the previous part of the .mod file that I excluded in the following code.)

```
set A{s in 1..S, t in 1..T} default {};
for {s in 1..S} {
    for {t in 1..T} {
        /*set A{s,t} default {};*/
        for {sprime in 1..S: sprime != s}{
            if B[sprime,t] = B[s,t] then {
                let A[s,t] := A[s,t] union {sprime};
            }   
        }
    } 
}
```

I tried commenting out the first line and uncommenting the 4th line; however, it did not help.

In short, what I'm trying to do is to have an empty A matrix sized SxT and then fill/update each element of that matrix with nested for loops. So, every element of the matrix will contain a set. The sizes of these elements/sets can be different.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following code and it seems to do what you wanted, without error messages:

```
reset;
param S := 5;
param T := 3;

model;
param B{1..S,1..T};
data;
param B: 1 2 3 :=
1   1 2 3 
2   2 3 2
3   0 0 3 
4   1 1 1
5   3 2 3
;
model;

set A{s in 1..S, t in 1..T} default {};
for {s in 1..S}{
    for {t in 1..T}{
        for {sprime in 1..S: sprime != s}{
            if B[sprime,t] = B[s,t] then {
                let A[s,t] := A[s,t] union {sprime}};
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't significantly modified the part that you posted, just added some definitions so it's self-contained. However, I do have a "reset" at the beginning of the script.

Is it possible that you forgot to clear definitions of A in between runs? If so, then you would get an "A is already defined" error, not because of the LET statements but because of the "set A" statement at the start of your code snippet.